# How much memory could vm use

Tags: linux-kernel

I read the document [**Understanding Virtual Memory**](http://www.redhat.com/magazine/001nov04/features/vm/) and it said one method for changing tunable parameters in the Linux VM was the command:

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=65535
```

I want to know what the number 65535 means and how much memory could vm use by the setting.

Comment: I know 65535 is the default, I want to know how I should calculate the real memory vm could use

Comment: Hi, found something here - [Article](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P145538) it's written there 256MB.

Comment: i think it can not say 256MB simply here, because at my system vm.max_map_count=65535, but my erlang vm had used about 8GB memory and it was ok

Comment: This suppose to be the source of the article which i mentioned above [Source](http://www.psdn.progress.com/realtime/techsupport/documentation/objectstore/r60/ostore/doc/rnotes/chap1.htm) - i didn't really understand what you mean in the above comment

Comment: It does not determine directly how much memory a process can use. A process can allocate memory let's say in 64Kb chunks or 256Kb chunks, having 4x different total memory used. vm.max_map_count controls only number of these chunks..

Answer (score 119, accepted):

From [the Linux kernel documentation](http://kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt):

> max_map_count:
>
> This file contains the maximum number of memory map areas a process
>   may have. Memory map areas are used as a side-effect of calling
>   malloc, directly by mmap and mprotect, and also when loading shared
>   libraries.
>
> While most applications need less than a thousand maps, certain
>   programs, particularly malloc debuggers, may consume lots of them,
>   e.g., up to one or two maps per allocation.
>
> The default value is 65536.

Bottom line: this setting limits the *number* of discrete mapped memory *areas* - on its own it imposes no limit on the *size* of those areas or on the memory that is usable by a process.

And yes, this:

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=65535
```

is just a nicer way of writing this:

```
echo 65535 > /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count
```

Comment: It looks like I misinterpreted vm.max_map_count mean

Comment: possibly additional interesting information: https://ynuxtechblog.wordpress.com/2016/01/05/getting-your-system-parameters-right-in-dockered-elasticsearch/#vm.max_map_count

Comment: Could you explain, what the negative effects might be if increasing the default?

Comment: Not just a "nicer way", the `sysctl` approach is the *persistent* way to apply this kernel change.  With the `echo` approach the memory settings will be reverted to the original value after a node recycle.  Good to be aware of if changing to a non-default value.

Comment: @user9074332, this actually isn't true. Both ways of changing (`sysctl -w` and `echo > /proc/sys/*`) aren't persistent. To make the changes persistent you should modify `/etc/sysctl.conf` and then (optionally) execute `sysctl -p` to apply the changes without reboot.

Comment: @user1767754 https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000016692

Answer (score 21):

```
echo 'vm.max_map_count=262144' >> /etc/sysctl.conf

sysctl -p
```

Answer (score 6):

```
echo "vm.max_map_count=262144" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
sysctl -p
```

This does not work since we cannot change the configuration file directly.
Run the below command.

```
echo vm.max_map_count=262144 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
```

But check if `vm.max_map_count` already exists or not. You can do that using

```
grep vm.max_map_count /etc/sysctl.conf
```