# What is the maximum size of acceptable data in the mmap function in c?

Tags: c, linux, unix, memory-management, mmap

Let's suppose that there is a large file. The    `mmap`    function cannot handle it entirely. But we need to read as large parts of this file as possible.

I found that this command in Unix allows us to find the    `mmap`   size:

```
sysctl vm.max_map_count
```

The output is: `vm.max_map_count = 65530`.

However, it doesn't work in C program. How to find the size of map function in C program?

Comment: Seems to me you have misunderstood the parameter. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683850/how-much-memory-could-vm-use

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit on how big mmappings are (except for the bits in `size_t`), as the kernel never needs to load the entire thing into memory at once. `mmap()` is the method of choice for reading files larger than your memory: Just map the file, and let the kernel worry about the rest...