# Is there a maximum number of continuous pages per process in Linux? If so, how to set it to unlimited?

Tags: c, linux

The following code will generate errno 12 cannot allocate memory

```c
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <errno.h>
int main()
{
    char* p;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 0x10000; i++)
    {
        char* addr = (char*)0xAAA00000000uL - i * 0x2000;
        p = mmap(addr, 0x1000,
            PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
        if (p != addr) {
            printf("%lu %d\n", i, errno);
            getchar();
            return 1;
        }
        memset(p, 'A' + (i % 26), 0x1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `65510 12` on my machine.

However, if we change size of each page from 0x1000 to 0x2000, the allocation will be successful, even if it is using more memory.
The only difference I think is the number of continuous pages, is there a limitation on this? If so, how to set it to unlimited?

Comment: There aren't really contiguous _pages_ (page slots) in virtual memory per se. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37173063/5382650 then the answer linked in the answer and the two links in the comments below the answer

Answer (score 1):

It seems that setting `/proc/sys/vm/max_map_count` to a larger number solves the problem.
Reference: [How much memory could vm use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683850/how-much-memory-could-vm-use)