# Solr stopped with Error opening new searcher at org.apache.solr.core

Tags: java, solr, lucene

Yesterday suddenly our solr server got stopped with following exception

> org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher at
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:1438) at
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:1550) at
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:1319) at
>   org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.commit(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:574)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processCommit(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:95)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processCommit(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:64)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processCommit(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:1147)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor.processCommit(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:157)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:266)
>   at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:173)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:92)
>
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Map failed at
>   sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:889) at
>   org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory.map(MMapDirectory.java:283) at
>   org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory$MMapIndexInput.

But at that time we have lot of memory left in that server. Any guess?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming its a linux system you can try `ulimit -v unlimited`

Check the below links for more information.

https://support.lucidworks.com/hc/en-us/articles/206127457-Caused-by-java-io-IOException-Map-failed

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8893684/689625

You will get answers much faster if you include more information, like the version of your software (in this case solr version), OS Name and version, Java version etc.

Comment: there is any considerations before doing this?

Answer (score 2):

The flag -fix didn't work in my later version, instead I used exorcise

```
java -cp lucene-core-5.5.0.jar -ea:org.apache.lucene... org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex PATH_TO_INDEX -exorcise
```

I hope this could help.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error:

```
Error creating core [mm_shard1_replica1]: Error opening new searcher
```

and tried fiddling with `ulimit` and `max_map_count`

In the end it turned out to be a bad error message because the problem turned out to be a corrupt index.

Fixed it by shutting down solr and doing this:

```
cd /var/lib/solr/example/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/lib
java -cp lucene-core-4.10.4.jar -ea:org.apache.lucene... org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex /path/to/index -fix
```

To just check wether the index is broken remove the `-fix` at the end of above command. After that I started up solr and it recreated its index from the rest of the solrcloud cluster.